# Mysql query to determine if the given datetime is included in the datetime interval

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm stucked  on this task where if the given datetime falls in between the start and end date.
For example, here is a table of calendar data:

```
| id |  start               | end

| 31 | 2017-03-15 05:21:30  | 2017-03-15 06:21:30 
| 32 | 2017-03-14 06:25:30  | 2017-03-14 06:25:30 
| 33 | 2017-03-14 06:25:45  | 2017-03-14 06:25:45
```

And I have to insert new data into the table with the following start and end datetimes:

`start: 2017-03-15 05:30:30`
`end: 2017-03-15 06:30:30`

But before that I have to check if the start and end date is existing in any datetime intervals in my table.

The result should be that the given start and end dates will not be inserted because it falls or it is included between the table id 31 datetime interval.

How should I be able to do that using a query? I tried this kind of query: `Select * from calendar_date as c where c.start >= start AND c.end <= end`
to determine that the given start and end datetime exists but no results found and I think I messed up with the query. I really hope that someone could help me check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Select * from calendar_date as ,c where LEAST(c.end, end) - GREATEST(c.start, start) > 0
```

Comment: This isn't an insert, it's a select.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Could you explain more please?

Comment: @dotNet, I have manually add start and end datetime for my query: 
```select * from calendar_item as c where TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, LEAST(c.end, "2017-03-15 06:30:30") - GREATEST(c.start, "2017-03-15 05:30:30")) > 0;``` but I have prompted for an error in my syntax. Thank you by the way for your answer.

Comment: @dotNET, you're great man! It works! Yes, yes I will convert it.

Comment: Now I have to convert this one to Doctrine query builder.

Comment: @G.Curs: Glad it helped. You don't need to convert if u r using one of the standard MySQL formats such as `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for whether a time range overlaps another one **at all**, the trick is to check whether there are any rows with the following conditions:

```
@end > t1.start
AND
@start < t1.end
```

Here `@start` and `@end` represent the start and end of the time window I'm comparing against the table.

This is mentally painful every time I look at it because it's counterintuitively simple.

If the time window in question ends after an existing window starts *and* starts before the existing windoe ends, then there is necessarily an overlap.

The proof of the logic is found in the conditions that cause the expression above to be false -- if either comparison evaluates to false, the combined expression is false:

If the new window does not end after an established window starts, then it necessarily ends before the established window starts, and therefore does not overlap. (Condition 1, `@end > t1.start`).

If the new window does not start before an established window ends, then it necessarily starts after the established window ends, and therefore does not overlap (Condition 2, `@start < t1.end`).

As written, this query does not match windows that touch precisely -- a window starting at exactly the end of another or ending at exactly the start of another -- is allowed. If you don't want this, either, use `>=` and `<=`.

To block an insert, you need a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS calendar_date_bi $$
CREATE TRIGGER calendar_date_bi
  BEFORE INSERT ON calendar_date
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM calendar_date cd
             WHERE NEW.end > cd.start AND NEW.start < cd.end) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'overlapping date ranges are not allowed';
  END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```