# Convert SQL to Doctrine with LEAST and GREATEST functions

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need your help on how am I going to convert the following Mysql to Doctrine.

```
select * from calendar_data as c where LEAST(c.end, end) - GREATEST(c.start, start) > 0;
```

I tried this one:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('items')
                ->from('\Admin\Entity\CalendarData','items')
                ->where('LEAST(items.end, :end) - GREATEST(items.start, :start) > 0')
                ->setParameter('start',$start)
                ->setParameter('end', $end);
```

(Given that `$start` and `$end` is already provided)

and I have the following error:

```
{
 "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
 "title": "Internal Server Error",
 "status": 500,
 "detail": "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected known function,   got 'LEAST'"
}
```

How should I do that?

This is the generated sql to my question:

[Mysql query to determine if the given datetime is included in the datetime interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42801817/mysql-query-to-determine-if-the-given-datetime-is-included-in-the-datetime-inter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no LEAST and GREATES functions in Doctrine. you can rewrite your query to achieve the same result or use ResultSetMapping, like

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$start = '';
$end = '';
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('CalendarData', 'c');
$rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'start', 'start');
$rsm->addFieldResult('c', 'end', 'end');

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('select * from calendar_data where LEAST(c.end, ?) - GREATEST(c.start, ?) > 0;', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $end);
$query->setParameter(2, $start);

$calendarData = $query->getResult();
```

Read about native sql in doctrine [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: Hi @Denis, the calendar data table is softdeleted and whenever I ran the native code on selecting the calendar data where column deleted_at is NULL, it shows no result even if there should be results since the column deleted is NULL. I don't know why this happens. My query looks like this:
```select * from calendar_data as c where LEAST(c.end, "2017-03-14 11:18:30") - GREATEST(c.start, "2017-03-14 10:18:30") > 0 AND c.deleted_at = NULL;``` . I noticed it looks up also with other data where the column deleted_at is not null.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Beberlei's DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) to extend DQL with many more MySQL functions such as `GREATEST` and `LEAST`.

1. Install the library => `composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions`
2. Add the functions you need to your config.yml

   ```
   doctrine:
       orm:
           dql:
               string_functions:
                   least: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Least
                   greatest: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Greatest
   ```

After installing and linking, your first try at converting the code should work as expected:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $qb->select('items')
                ->from('\Admin\Entity\CalendarData','items')
                ->where('LEAST(items.end, :end) - GREATEST(items.start, :start) > 0')
                ->setParameter('start',$start)
                ->setParameter('end', $end);
```